# How to generate older pmml version in R

Tags: r, pmml

The pmml package in R by default generates pmml of the most recent version (at the moment 4.2). Is it possible (and if so, how?) to generate pmml of older versions (e.g. 4.1), because the pmml consumer doesn't support 4.2 yet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several options:

- Install an older version of the `pmml` package. The PMML schema version 4.2 was released in February 2014, so all `pmml` package versions that predate this event should produce older PMML schema versions.
- Change the XML namespace declaration of your XML result object manually from `http://www.dmg.org/PMML-4_2` to `http://www.dmg.org/PMML-4_1`. PMML schema versions are mostly backwards compatible, so it shouldn't be a problem.
- Use an external tool to convert the PMML file. For example, if you're comfortable with Java programming, then you can use the JPMML-Model library to safely convert between PMML schema versions 3.0 through 4.2. See this [blog post](http://openscoring.io/blog/2014/06/20/jpmml_model_api_import_export/) for a more detailed explanation.